# Problem starting geth node

Tags: go-ethereum

2018/03/16 17:41:20 ssdp: got unexpected search target result "urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:WANConnectionDevice:1"

2018/03/16 17:41:20 ssdp: got unexpected search target result "urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:WANConnectionDevice:1"

2018/03/16 17:41:20 ssdp: got unexpected search target result "urn:schemas-upnp-org:device:WANConnectionDevice:1"

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, it's lately

But a fix it now

That problem is simply about connection, you have to verify your admin.nodeInfo when the geth is executing there is a ip and a port or [::port] if there is a IP take sure that it have access on localhost.

if don't have access start your process "geth" with parameter --nat extip:127.0.0.1

I ensure that it is right

Comment: Yes, it is right